# Trying to return DbSet of type BaseClass

Tags: c#, mocking, entity-framework-6

I am trying to return a DbSet of the type TEntity when it is a Baseclass.

What I have is two classes with a baseclass. They are both in the same table in the database.

```
private FakeDbSet<BaseClass> allclasses { get; set; }
```

[image]

So in my code I Set the right database by using the following code:

```
public DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>()
                where TEntity : class, IObjectState
        {
        var propertyInfos = GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in propertyInfos)
        {
            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(FakeDbSet<TEntity>))
                return property.GetValue(this) as FakeDbSet<TEntity>;
        }

        var baseType = typeof(TEntity).BaseType;

        while( typeof(object) != baseType )
        {
            foreach(var property in propertyInfos)
            {
                if(property.PropertyType == typeof(FakeDbSet<>).MakeGenericType(baseType))
                {
                    var baseTypeDbSet = property.GetValue(this);

                    // you will need to convert FakeDbSet<TBaseType> to FakeDbSet<TEntity>
                    //This is a try but it will not work!!!
                    var entityDbSet = Convert.ChangeType(baseTypeDbSet, typeof(FakeDbSet<>).MakeGenericType(baseType));
                    var result = entityDbSet as FakeDbSet<TEntity>;
                    return result;
                }
            }
            baseType = baseType.BaseType;
        }
```

**Now my problem is:** as you see I am trying to return a `FakeDbSet<TEntity>`. When I do `Set<Class1>()` it comes in the second loop. The problem is that the function expect a return type of `FakeDbSet<TEntity>` (in this case `FakeDbSet<Class1>`) but I want to return the BaseClass in this case: `FakeDbSet<BaseClass>`.

Comment: Do you wish to return FakeDbSet<BaseClass> regardless of which derived class is supplied to the Set method?

Comment: Yes mostly, the function starts by checking if there is no FakeDbSet with the type of subclass and else it will search for a baseclass that has a FakeDbSet type.